# Category "same post" retreive and display

Tags: plugins, categories

I have made a multiple category. Each item belong to one or more category. So when display one item, i like to retreive the category of this item, and display all post that have belong to that category.

Example. Chair : cat = sit, leather, one person

So when display the chair, i like below to display all item that have : sit leather and one person as category

Is there a plugsin that do that ?, or in php it's simple to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# according to your example:
$categories = array ( 'sit', 'leather', 'one person'  );

# get all id's by the category names
foreach ($categories as $category_name) {
$category = get_term_by( 'name', $category_name , 'category' ); 
$ids[] = $category->term_id;
}

# get all posts for the categories
query_posts( 'cat='.join(',',$ids) );
```

Sorry, I cannot test it right now, this is just a guess till tomorrow.

Comment: And I think using $categories = get_the_category(); in the first line would get the categories of the post, if you want to do it that way